# How to remove the parent directory of a subdirectory from the URL (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, url, directory, url-rewriting

I have been trying every possible way of removing the subdirectory's parent directory from the URL.

Let's assume that this is my url: `https://example.com/accounts/login`. I need the url to look like this: `https://example.com/login`, so without the `accounts` directory.

And usually when I try to go to `https://example.com/login` I get "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request." (aka Error 500 - internal server error).

My current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ html/$1

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/jpg
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/jpeg
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>

Options -Indexes
```

Comment: @anubhava Here it is.

Comment: Sounds like a classical internal redirection loop. But since you explicitly claim that you tried every possible way to achieve what you look for without success there is nothing we can add, is there? Hint: the loop most likely is created by the combination of `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ html/$1` with whatever you tried to add (which you did not tell us).

Comment: @LeonKunštek: Thanks but I don't see any rule here that is adding `accounts` internally to URLs.

Comment: @anubhava Because I deleted all of the code connected to the `accounts` folder

Comment: @anubhava None of it worked so I removed it.

Comment: But looks like you already have a similar rule for adding `html/` folder, what is purpose of that rule?

Comment: @anubhava It's to remove the `html` folder but for some reason it doesn't work for the `accounts` and I've tried moving the rule for the `accounts` up and down the .htaccess file and it still doesn't work (I thought that it had something to do with me not closing the rewrite engine or something else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace **all of your rewrite rules** with this block:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/html/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ html/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/html/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ html/$1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/accounts/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ accounts/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/accounts/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ accounts/$1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: +1 For the code. I just avoided the `accounts` folder all together and placed the login folder in the root directory and now it works. I'm going to mark your answer as "The Answer" all though it isn't.